# How to concert [{ id:1, var1:val1, var2:val2, varX:[time1, time2, time3]}] into [{id:1, var1:val1, var2:val2, varX1:time1, varX2:time2, varX3:time3}]

Tags: javascript

I am working on a data format transformation which showed on the title, but I don't know how to figure out. I have tried to write the blow code to add the variable name for second dimensional array:

```
const data = [
  { id: 1, var1: 'val1', var2: 'val2', varX: ['time1', 'time2', 'time3'] },
  { id: 2, var1: 'val2', var2: 'val3', varX: ['time4', 'time5', 'time6'] },
];

const test = data.map((o) => o.varX);

for (i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  const test2 = test[i].reduce((res, cur, idx) => {
    res[`varX${idx}`] = cur;
    return res;
  }, {});
  console.log(test2);
}
```

but what I expected result should be:

```
[{id:1, var1:val1, var2:val2, varX1:time1, varX2:time2, varX3:time3},{id:2, var1:val2, var2:val3, varX1:time4, varX2:time5, varX3:time6}]
```

Could anyone can guide me how to convert the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you're extracgint the properties that are not `varX` from the `data` by mapping only the values that have a `varX`. Then you do a good job at reducing them, but then you would have to merge the "left over" properties into the new object, it sounds a bit cumbersome to me. Instead, you could do something like the following:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, var1: "val1", var2: "val2", varX: ["time1", "time2", "time3"] },
  { id: 2, var1: "val2", var2: "val3", varX: ["time4", "time5", "time6"] },
];

const test = data.map((o) => {
  return Object.entries(o).reduce((p, [k, v]) => {
    if (k === "varX") {
      for (let index = 0; index < v.length; index++) {
        p[`varX${index + 1}`] = v[index];
      }
    } else {
      p[k] = v;
    }
    return p;
  }, {});
});

console.log(test);
```

First, you map the data objects, then for each object you reduce their key/value pairs and check if the property is `varX`, if so, then you iterate through the array and assign to the new object the `varX${index + 1}` since you want the first property to be `varX1`, otherwise you just keep the same key/value pair.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the first map in `test`, you are operating only on values of `varX`.  You can just add another operation to merge the original `data[i]` objects with your new reduced `varX` objects.

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, var1: 'val1', var2: 'val2', varX: ['time1', 'time2', 'time3'] },
  { id: 2, var1: 'val2', var2: 'val3', varX: ['time4', 'time5', 'time6'] },
];

const test = data.map((o) => o.varX);

for (i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  const test2 = test[i].reduce((res, cur, idx) => {
    res[`varX${idx}`] = cur;
    return res;
  }, {});
  // exclude varX and merge your new varX${i} back into data[i]
  const {varX, ...test3} = Object.assign(data[i], test2);
  console.log(test3);
}
```

Transform in-place code.  I've deliberately avoided reduce, because the syntax becomes less readable and it adds performance overhead.  The downside is that this code mutates the original `data` (transforms the data in-place).  Can be easily mitigated by creating copies of objects `val` while mapping.

```js
[1,2,3,4,5,6].forEach( i => eval(`time${i} = "time${i}";val${i} = "val${i}"`) );

const data = [{id:1, var1:val1, var2:val2, varX:[time1, time2, time3]}, {id:2, var1:val2, var2:val3, varX:[time4, time5, time6]}]

data.forEach((val, i)=>{
  val.varX.forEach( (X,i) => val[`varX${i}`]=X );
  delete val.varX;
  console.log(val);
  return val;
});
console.log(data);
```

I've created a version below using reduce and spread syntax.  You can look at the spread syntax as simply an operation to copy properties to the new object being generated.  I've used destructuring syntax to isolate `varX` from the rest of the properties and put them in `varX` and `noVarX`.

This also has the advantage of deep copying except for the final outside referenced objects in data.

```js
  [1,2,3,4,5,6].forEach( i => eval(`time${i} = "time${i}";val${i} = "val${i}"`) );

  const data = [{id:1, var1:val1, var2:val2, varX:[time1, time2, time3]}, {id:2, var1:val2, var2:val3, varX:[time4, time5, time6]}]
  const expanded = data.map(val => {
    const {varX, ...noVarX} = val;
    return {
      ...noVarX,
      ...varX.reduce( (res, cur, idx) => 
          ({ ...res, [`varX${idx}`]: cur }), {})
    };
  });
  console.log(expanded);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need create objects in `reduce`method instead array, after replace `varX` to this new object by second `map()` method

```js
const data = [{'id':1, 'var1':'val1', 'var2':'val2', 'varX':['time1', 'time2', 'time3']}, 
            {'id':2, 'var1':'val2', 'var2':'val3', 'varX':['time4', 'time5', 'time6']}]

const test = data.map(item => item.varX);
const test2 = {}
for (i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
            test2[i] = test[i].reduce((accum, item, index) => {
              return { ...accum, [`varX${index}`]: item};
            }, {});
          }

const dataX = data.map((item, index) => {
  delete item.varX
  return { ...item, ...test2[index] }
});
 
console.log(dataX)
```